# Protractor - How to Get Value from an Object to Manipulate Value Outside the Promise

Tags: javascript, object, testing, promise, protractor

Here is the issue I am trying to get value from object inside a promise. I am trying to get the 1st element from a column (Kendo grid). Need to manipulate the value.

**Here is the code:**

```
currentAmountDue =  element(((helper.getGridValue(businessPaymentsPage.colAmountDue(), 0)).getText().then(function (value) {
              x = value;
                console.log('x: ', x);
                console.log('Value : ', value);
                return value;
            })));
console.log('x outside : ', x);
```

**Here are the results:**

```
x outside :  0

x:  $9,750.75

Value :  $9,750.75
```

I am new to Protractor and Promises.

Comment: Is var x declared as a window variable? if so, have you tried setTimeout(function(){console.log('x outside : ', x);},1000); ? The code inside the then promise function is executed before the console log you are printing. That is why x outside is printed before the one inside your function.

Comment: @RobertoNovelo note that this is a protractor specific question.

Comment: he is trying to get the value of the variable inside the promise function immediately though, isn't it why it is being printed before the ones inside the function?

Comment: Thanks! Everyone who answer.  I figured out that I had to do the additional processing in the promise.  Once, the promise is satisfied, the value outside will always be zero (or undefined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside the `then` block will be executed later.  `getText()` is an asynchronous method that returns a promise that will be resolved when the text is actually fetched (which will happen later).

In general, with promises, you need to chain dependent code off the code it depends on with `then`, so make your "outside" code run inside a `then`.  In practice, most of the top-level protractor methods register their promises with a ControlFlow that makes sure the promises are resolved in order.  This minimizes the number of explicit `then` chains, but does make the code a bit more magical.  (The controlflow infrastructure is part of WebDriverJS that Protractor builds on.)

Read https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md and https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#control-flows

Comment: Thanks !!  This helped more than you know.  I have started using chained promises. @P.T.